# Event handler firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have this very odd and strange situation. I attached a click listener to a radio-button just once. However, when I click the radio button, the listener function fires twice. I tried it using both jQuery and plain JS event handlers, and it's the same problem.

```js
$("#type_oneway").on("click", function(){ alert('clicked button'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="type_oneway" name="type" value="One Way" class="use_once" checked style="display:none;">
<label for="type_oneway" style="width:74px;">One Way</label>
<input type="radio" id="type_roundtrip" name="type"value="Roundtrip" class="use_once" style="display:none;">
<label for="type_roundtrip" style="width:74px;">Round Trip</label>
```

When I run the code and click the button, I get two alerts. I can't seem to figure out the reason.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/7xude9zo/, I think there is more going on than the code you posted

Comment: seems to be fine here https://jsfiddle.net/evvfmbtz/

Comment: Is your jQuery code inside of another function? If so, it's possible that the event listener is being set twice, which would cause it to trigger twice.

Comment: @DavidSherret, it works well in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xr7opywt/

Comment: I editted it, but left the syntax error of the OP.  You are missing a space in between `name="type"` and `value="Roundtrip"`.  Also labels are inline elements and can't have a width, so that's just being ignored.  Why put `style=dispaly:none` when you already have a `use_once` class?

Answer (score 2):

There could be another part of your script which causes the handler to be assigned twice. Just cancel any event handler that may be attached before adding a new event handler.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/LgpyLkku/1/))

```
$("#type_oneway").off('click').on("click", function(){ alert('clicked button'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not happening for me with the supplied code.  I've also cleaned it up.

```js
$("input").on("click", function(){ alert('clicked button'); });
```

```css
.use_once { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="type_oneway" name="type" value="One Way" class="use_once" checked>
<label for="type_oneway">One Way</label>
<input type="radio" id="type_roundtrip" name="type" value="Roundtrip" class="use_once">
<label for="type_roundtrip">Round Trip</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an identical element with the same tag that would cause `onclick` event to fire twice? That might be why. You are selecting all elements with the `.use_once`, That is possibly why it is firing twice, one time for One Way and one time for the Round Trip, If you want to do one at a time, I suggest using the jQuery selector `$("#use_once")` for your click event. You would have the id's values different.
To be more specific `$("#one_way")` , `$("#round_trip")`, for example.

Comment: Would a solution be to create two separate event handlers for his inputs?

Comment: So, the scenario is the opposite of what I stated,  selecting all elements with `$(".use_once")` would set the handler for both elements allowing it to fire once?

Answer (score 0):

You might have written the below code twice.

```
$("#type_oneway").on("click", function(){alert('clicked button');});
```

Please check it.